# Не переведено сообщение "thanks for the feedback" для участников с репутацией менее 125

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, голоса-против

Когда участник с репутацией меньше 125 пытается нажать на кнопку голосования «против», он получает следующее сообщение:

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Это сообщение не переведено на русский язык.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо бы перевести.

Comment: It should be translated now. Could you check it?

Comment: @Suvitruf - yep, looks like it was!

Comment: Excellent ٩(◕‿◕｡)۶ You can accept the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В трансе это [эти строки](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/135079455?q=text%3A'Thanks%20for%20the%20feedback!%20Votes%20cast%20by%20those%20with%20less%20than'). Перевод добавил. Нужно, чтоб админы в паблик запушили его.

Предложенный вариант:

> Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 125
>   учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.

Можно "не меняют" заменить на "не влияют".

Comment: В подобных ситуациях хорошо бы приводить текст предложенного перевода, так как сообщество может предложить варианты его улучшения сразу по месту.

Comment: @alexolut учту на будущее. Сейчас добавлю в ответ.

Comment: @alexolut да и толку. Aer всё равно свой вариант добавит :D

Comment: Были прецеденты?

Comment: @alexolut насколько я вижу по трансу Aer свой вариант использовал "Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с [репутацией]($link$), которая меньше $repRequired$, учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга. "

Comment: Я бы предпочел "менее", чем "которая меньше", если честно.

Comment: @alexolut ну, нас не спрашивали)

Comment: там был только вариант для one в такой форме. Я сделал единообразно, хотя фактически one и не используется никогда.